# Microsoft Ajax Toolkit References

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I downloaded and installed the Ajax Toolkit Microsoft provides into my copy of Visual Studio.  I'm trying to follow online examples of using the controls and I ran into the following discrepancy.  I have installed the toolkit and it's accessible through the toolbox.  I have added a reference to this particular project
[image]

but when I drag and drop the AutoCompleteExtender control from the toolkit I see some difference ASP.  I see something like

```
<asp:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

but all of the examples that I've seen show syntax like `<ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender>`
however, when I try to use that syntax I get a warning `unrecognized tag prefix or device filter 'ajaxToolkit'.
proof the ToolKit is installed

[image]

What is different here?  Intellisense doesn't pick up on the ajaxToolkit tag and even after adding a using statement for everything in the AjaxToolkit namespace I still get the warning message of the unrecognized tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The examples you are following are probably written at the time when Ajax Toolkit wasn't part of ASP.NET, so you had to manually add the references into your project (in web.config) and usually they were added in a way that you'd use tags that begin with `<ajaxToolkit:` You could change that into any kind of prefix.

Now that it's part of ASP.NET, you don't need to create a separate reference (it's probably automatically added), so they used normal `<asp:` tag prefix.

Comment: I thought this as well initially, but then some of the examples I saw written last year used the `<ajaxToolKit>` way.  Good to get verification, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This part of the tag name is the Prefix, and you (or the library) set it either on the page that you drop your control, either on the web.config as global setup.

On the page, on the top, but under the first first declaration line:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" 
    TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>
```

on the `web.config` to make it global and not need to add it on every page:

```
<pages >
  <controls>
    <add namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" />
  </controls>
</pages>
```

If you see on this two examples I have set as TagPrefix the one you have see on the examples.

Comment: setting this up using web.config seems like the best solution to me.  thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could be using the wrong version of the toolkit with your ASP.net installation.

I found out the hard way that I had to be sure I was using the right version of ASP.net. I was trying to use a 3.5 AjaxToolKit DLL with an ASP.net 2 version of my website.

I simply placed this line on top of my ASPX page and it's been fine since.

```
<%@ Register Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
    Namespace="System.Web.UI" TagPrefix="asp" %>
```